# Android - Ellipsize & Truncate all long Urls in a Textview

Tags: android, textview, ellipsis, spannablestring

In my android app's textview, I want to ellipsis all URLs (which already have been linked using clickable span) to get ellipsis (or truncate) if the length of URL is greater than a certain limit.

This behaviour is inspired from twitter and facebook.

For example, the link http://www.getfluttr.com/flap/3rL7/now-only-if-modi-would-listen-to-opposition-party-/ it should look something like this:

[image]
(Screenshot Source: Twitter)

I understand that this has to involve spans. I can't seem to be able to find a span that'll allow me to replace text while keeping link.

Comment: Can't you use the `maxLength` and `ellipsize` XML attributes of the TextView?

Comment: @GSala hey. Thanks. Actually the links need not occur in the end. It can be anywhere and in any number in the TextView.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the following code will do the trick for you

```
public class LinkShortener {

    public static final int MAX_LINK_LENGTH = 20;

    public static CharSequence shortenLinks(String text) {
        return shortenLinks(text, Linkify.ALL);
    }

    public static CharSequence shortenLinks(String text, int linkMask) {
        SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
        Linkify.addLinks(builder, linkMask);
        URLSpan[] spans = builder.getSpans(0, builder.length(), URLSpan.class);
        for (URLSpan span : spans) {
            int start = builder.getSpanStart(span);
            int end = builder.getSpanEnd(span);
            int flags = builder.getSpanFlags(span);

            CharSequence linkText = builder.subSequence(start, end);
            if (linkText.length() > MAX_LINK_LENGTH) {
                linkText = linkText.subSequence(0, 20) + "…";
                builder.replace(start, end, linkText);
                builder.removeSpan(span);
                builder.setSpan(span, start, start+linkText.length(), flags);
            }
        }
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Then you can simply use it like this:

```
 itemView.setText(LinkShortener.shortenLinks("https://example.com/really_long_url"));
```

You might need to disable autoLink on the text view

The code first linkifies the text using the build in Android tooling. Then it goes through all creates URLSpans, and shortens the text via replace. Lastly we change the span to make sure it has the right bounds. Since we are reusing the existing span, the URL will be preserved

Comment: Thanks Filip. Wonderful solution! I was trying to work with SpannableString. Your solution worked like a charm.

Comment: the problem with this is that you can no longer clic on links

Comment: @RenaudFavier Are you sure? I don't see that problem

Comment: well, on my device, clics now redirect to "http://examp..." and no longer to the actual url. When I use "android:autoLink="all" " in xml I mean

Comment: If i don't use autolink, links are not clicables

Comment: this works... kinda, when clicked on a shortend url it just goes there, not to the full one... so this does not work for me

Comment: it only works if you have autolink in xml enabled aswell but then it wil try to go to the shortened url not the real url... so i fixed this by handeling the onclick manually for now

Answer (score 2):

I added some "pretty" updates to @Filip Wieladek answer based on Twitter behaviour.
The provided code first removes the **http(s)://www.** prefixes providing up to **12 characters** for more usefull information. It also perfectly matches the question desired behaviour. Example:

- https://www.stackove... (20 chars)
- stackoverflow.com/que... (20 chars without prefix)

Code

```
public static CharSequence shortenLinks(String text, int linkMask) {
    SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    Linkify.addLinks(builder, linkMask);
    URLSpan[] spans = builder.getSpans(0, builder.length(), URLSpan.class);
    for (URLSpan span : spans) {
        int start = builder.getSpanStart(span);
        int end = builder.getSpanEnd(span);
        int flags = builder.getSpanFlags(span);

        CharSequence linkText = builder.subSequence(start, end);
        if (linkText.length() > MAX_LINK_LENGTH) {

            // 1 - Remove the https:// or http:// prefix
            if(linkText.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("https://"))
                linkText = linkText.subSequence("https://".length(), linkText.length());
            else if(linkText.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("http://"))
                linkText = linkText.subSequence("http://".length(), linkText.length());

            // 2 - Remove the www. prefix
            if(linkText.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith("www."))
                linkText = linkText.subSequence("www.".length(), linkText.length());

            // 3 - Truncate if still longer than MAX_LINK_LENGTH
            if (linkText.length() > MAX_LINK_LENGTH) {
                linkText = linkText.subSequence(0, MAX_LINK_LENGTH) + "…";
            }

            // 4 - Replace the text preserving the spans
            builder.replace(start, end, linkText);
            builder.removeSpan(span);
            builder.setSpan(span, start, start+linkText.length(), flags);
        }
    }
    return builder;
}
```