# Android TextView elipsize end not working together with autolink

Tags: android, textview, autolink

The `ellipsize` property of the `TextView` is no longer working after setting `autoLink="all"`.
My code for the `TextView` is:

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/md_tv_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:autoLink="all"
            android:drawablePadding="24dp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="3"
            android:text="www.google.com Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
            industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown p
            rinter took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
             centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popula
             rised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently wi
             th desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_info_grey" />
```

Comment: I also had this issue some time back, the only solution I could find is this --- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33635908

Comment: @H.Brooks I don't think that shortening the link will work for me. I think you understood, but I'm not looking for that.
http://imgur.com/a/YEYJs
I'm just looking for ellipsis to show that there is more text that is not shown.

Comment: @Vlad did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @yausername I did not.